# Fill ImageView with drawable while keeping its aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I am making a video player and previewing the video's thumbnails in gridview. Is there any way to make  the thumbnails fill the gridview completely, by perhaps zooming in the image till both sides are >= grid size. Something like CSS `background-size: cover`, if that makes things clear

**Activity Layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/videos_grid"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Grid Item Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="384dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/video_item_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/video_thumbnail"
        android:background="@drawable/video_item_background"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/video_item_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### android:scaleType

```
<ImageView
    ...
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

This makes the smaller edge of drawable == ImageView's size while keeping the aspect ratio